# How do I include one specific file from an ignored folder Structure in a Perforce stream?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am setting up a Perforce Depot for my Cryengine Project and I want to ignore the `/bin` folder, but include the `Game.dll` file that is located at `/bin/win_x64/Game.dll`. I am not using a .p4ignore file but I am doing it via the ignore list in a stream inside the Helix Visual Client so it works per default on all machines.

I've found several pages that said I could add exceptions to ignore list by adding an `!` in front of the thing I want to include. I've tried that in several different ways, but it does not seem to work.

First I tried like this:

```
/bin/...
!Game.dll
```

Then like this:

```
/bin/...
!/bin/win_x64/Game.dll
```

But none seemed to be working.

When I try to add the file to the depot, it says `file(s) not in client view` regardles of what I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Ignored` field takes precedence over everything else and doesn't have an exclusion syntax.  However, if you put the `bin` folder in the `Paths` field you can add an exclusion and then override it:

```
Paths:
    share   ...
    exclude bin/...
    share   bin/win_x64/Game.dll
```

This gives you a view that looks like (whitespace added for readability):

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 where ...
 //stream/main/...                  //Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/...                  c:\Perforce\test\...
-//stream/main/bin/...              //Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/bin/...              c:\Perforce\test\bin\...
 //stream/main/bin/win_x64/Game.dll //Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/bin/win_x64/Game.dll c:\Perforce\test\bin\win_x64\Game.dll
```